# Finding/Understanding the Shadow Price of a Variable

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, simplex-method

So, I was working on my assignment for an online course and there's something I didn't understand very well. The teacher gave us this model:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\max & z=3x_1 + 4x_2 \\
s.t. & 2x_1 + 3x_2 \le 1200 \\
& 2x_1 + x_2 \le 1000 \\
& x_1 + 4x_2 \le 800 \\
& x_1, x_2 \ge 0 
\end{matrix}
$$

And proceeded to give us the tableau for the final iteration of the Simplex Method, which looked like this:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
B & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & b \\ \hline
x_3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -0.714 & -0.571 & 28.571 \\ \hline
x_1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0.571 & -0.142 & 457.142 \\ \hline
x_2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -0.142 & 0.285 & 85.7142 \\ \hline
z & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.142 & 0.714 & 1714.285
\end{array}\right]
$$

And finally asked us for the shadow price of $x_1$ and $x_2$ - this is where I got confused, as I thought shadow prices referred to the restrictions, not the variables.

> Is there such thing as a shadow price for the variable? If so, what is its meaning and how could I find it?

All resources I found online seem to confirm that suspicion, so I don't know how to proceed. Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: I share your confusion and suspect your teacher is confused. You should ask for a clarification.

Comment: @LinAlg So, I checked, and seems like it's asking if I decide to produce let's say one more x1 than what is given in the optimal solution, how much would that cost me?

Comment: You should have three slack variables, as you have three constraints.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 there are, x3, x4 and x5

Comment: My bad. You're right.  Do you know how to read dual solution from optimal simplex tableau?  The dual objective function is the RHS in the primal problem.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Yes, I do, but that would refer to the constraints, right? Not the variables x1 and x2

Comment: "It may be shown, using the approach of Winston (1995, pp250- 255, 293-300) that the shadow prices corresponding to the constraints of a primal LP problem are equal to the optimal values of teh dual variables."  I searched "shawdow price linear programming" and I found https://ideas.repec.org/p/fth/nesowa/96-18.html#:~:text=In%20linear%20programming%20problems%20the,is%20increased%20by%20one%20unit. showing the abstract of Alaouze, C.M., 1996. "Shadow Prices in Linear Programming Problems," Papers 96/18, New South Wales - School of Economics.

Comment: Sorry again, I forgot the definition of shadow price for a few years, since I've never used linear programming in my studies in proba & stats.

Answer (score 1):

To start, let us map out the Simplex Tableau as such:

\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline BV & z & \text{Variables} & RHS & RT \\
        \hline z & 1 & C_{BV}^TB^{-1}N-C_{NBV}^T & C_{BV}^TB^{-1}b & - \\
        \hline x_n & 0 &  &  &  \\
        \text{or} & 0 & B^{-1}A &  &  \\ 
        s_n & \vdots & \text{or} & B^{-1}b & \frac{B^{-1}b}{B^{-1}A_j} \\
        \text{or} & 0 & B^{-1}A_j &  &  \\
        e_n & 0 &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{array}

In order to figure out the "Shadow Price" of a Basic Variable (which is really the amount of allowable of change in the original coefficient of a Basic Variable before it changes our current basis) is calculated by the following equation:

$$C^\pi_j=C^T_{BV}B^{-1}Ax_j-Cx_j$$

Where $B^{-1}$ is the entire matrix under the cost-coefficients of the slack variables in the tableau, $A_j$ is the original column coefficients from the constraint of the original model of the chosen variable to calculate, and $C_j$ is the original (non-standardized) cost coefficient in the objective function of the chosen variable.

This will be made more understandable via an Example:

Suppose we want to measure the amount of allowed change of a a basic variable of the following model:

$$\max z = 3x_1+5x_2$$
$$\text{Subject to:}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$
$$x_1\le4$$
$$2x_2\le12$$
$$3x_1+2x_2\le18$$
$$x_1,x_2\ge0$$

and it has the following optimal final tableau:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
BV & z &x_1 & x_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & RHS \\ \hline
  z & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{2}  & 1 & 36 \\ \hline
s_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & 2\\
x_2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 6\\
x_1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 2\\
\hline
\end{array}

and we wanted to measure the amount of change if we were to change the original cost of the basic variable $x_2$, then we can measure the allowable amount of change by doing the following to each non-basic variable in the basis:

$$c^\pi_{s_2} = [0, \Delta, 3]B^{-1}A_{s_2}-0$$
$$=[0, \Delta, 3]
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3}\\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\Longrightarrow c^\pi_{s_2} = \frac{1}{2}\Delta - 1 \ge 0$$
$$\text{(We don’t want to change the basis)}$$
$$\Longrightarrow\Delta\ge2$$

and,

$$c^\pi_{s_3} = [0, \Delta, 3]B^{-1}A_{s_3}-0$$
$$= [0, \Delta, 3]
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3}\\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\Longrightarrow c^\pi_{s_3} = 1$$
$$\text{(Changing $x_2$’s coefficient doesn’t effect $s_3$.)}$$

Thus, the allowable coefficients of $x_2$ that wouldn’t change the basis is $\Delta \ge 2$.

**Back to the Problem:**

What they may be asking us is the allowable amount of coefficient change of the basic variables $x_1$ and $x_2$, which would be the following for $x_1$:

$$C^\pi_j=[0, \Delta, 4]B^{-1}Ax_j-Cx_j$$
$$=[0, \Delta, 4]
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -0.714 & -0.571\\
0 & 0.571 & -0.142 \\
0 & -0.142 & 0.285
\end{bmatrix}Ax_j-Cx_j$$

For each non-basic variable in the tableau, and for $x_2$:

$$C^\pi_j=[0, 3, \Delta]B^{-1}Ax_j-Cx_j$$
$$=[0, 3, \Delta]
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -0.714 & -0.571\\
0 & 0.571 & -0.142 \\
0 & -0.142 & 0.285
\end{bmatrix}Ax_j-Cx_j$$

For each non-basic variable to determine the allowed change for the coefficients of the basic variables.

$$$$

**Otherwise**, if it isn’t this, then your instructor misspoke and meant the Shadow Price of the slack variables in which is the common convention of the term, which has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91504/1098096).